# Django similar url pattern issue

Tags: django, django-urls, slug

I am working on a products comparison module and have url patterns like below:

```
path('comparison/<slug:slug1>-vs-<slug:slug2>/', views.compare_two_products, name="compare_two_products"),
path('comparison/<slug:slug1>-vs-<slug:slug2>-vs-<slug:slug3>/', views.compare_three_products, name="compare_three_products"),
```

The issue is that Django (3.2.6) always matches the first pattern and returns 404 when I try to access the second pattern. However if I comment out the first pattern, then it matches the third pattern just fine. I want to get both the patterns working in the format **slug-vs-slug-vs-slug**. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order or URLs, like

```
path('comparison/<slug:slug1>-vs-<slug:slug2>-vs-<slug:slug3>/', views.compare_three_products, name="compare_three_products"),
path('comparison/<slug:slug1>-vs-<slug:slug2>/', views.compare_two_products, name="compare_two_products"),
```

that should work

Comment: Thanks @Sumithran never thought that the order would matter. But makes total sense after Django tries to match it with the first url which is similar.